# How to set a scene as initial view controller cocos2d

Tags: uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.3, uistoryboard

I am not sure how to correctly display code in a thread so sorry about that in advance.  So I have my App Delegate which calls

[director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]];

Then my introLayer does this:

```
-(void) makeTransition:(ccTime)dt
{
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[MainMenu scene] withColor:ccBLUE]];
}
```

Then I have MainMenu.h and .m but they are pretty much empty except .m has:

```
@implementation MainMenu

// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the GamePlay as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    MainMenu *layer = [MainMenu node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
@end
```

Then I have a storyboard which uses a navigation controller and I want the opening scene to be the main menu when i call the 'makeTransition' function.  In my storyboard I have a Play button on this main menu.  This play button is push segued to another view controller which is of class 'CCViewController'.  I have CCViewController.m and .h and then i made a subclass from it called cocos2dViewController.m and .h.  In my cocos2dViewController.m I call:

```
if(director.runningScene)

    [director replaceScene:[GamePlay scene]];

else

    [director pushScene:[GamePlay scene]];
```

GamePlay.m and .h are where i define my whole game.

So when I run it I get the launch screen and then it transitions with the color blue to a black screen.  Is this because there is nothing in MainMenu.m? Also, (I think) I shouldn't need anything in MainMenu.m. I just need some way of making the MainMenu scene be the initial (main menu) scene of the storyboard.  I feel that I am pretty close to getting this to work and any advice/knowledge you have to offer at this point or if you need any more info to diagnose the problem would again be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When there is no scene running in cocos2d, you should start one by calling `runScene`, not `replaceScene`.

This is the first thing you should try and change.

On the other hand, it seems to my that you are trying to display a cocos2d scene inside of a UIKit view controller. This also requires some care to work. If you are using cocos2d 2.0, have a look at [this post](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2012/02/07/cocos2d-and-storyboards/) for some hints.

Comment: I followed that tutorial to get to where I am right now.  Also you say this requires some care to work, is there a better way you could suggest to do this?  Thanks

Comment: well, as far as I understand, you should not be calling `makeTransition` as you have defined it. Simply instantiate your controller (according to the tutorial) and then segue to it - viewDidLoad (as per the tutorial) should do all that is required.

Comment: by the way, try and add some sprite to your `MainMenu` scene so see if it is displayed.

Comment: Well I'm almost there! I got it to display the menu but now when i click the Play button it doesn't show the game it just shows a black screen.

Comment: the line `[director pushScene:[GamePlay scene]]` should be `[director runWithScene:[MyScene scene]];
`

Comment: I tried that but its still black :(  Any other ideas as to why this is happening?  By the way i really appreciate you helping me out with this.  Thanks!